contour lua: make the exterior of the contour transparent
As a follow up to this question, I need to make the exterior of the contour transparent rather than white (as it is there), so I tried
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=ln((1+\x)^2+\y^2)+ln((1+(7*\x)/2)^2+(49*\y^2)/4)+ln((1+4*\x)^2+16*\y^2);
},
]
\fill[yellow!30] (0,0) rectangle (7,6);
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
enlargelimits,
colormap={CM}{color=(blue!50) color=(transparent)},
]
\addplot3[
contour filled={levels={1}},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
]{f(\x,\y)};
\addplot3[
contour lua={levels={1}, labels=false, draw color=blue},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
thick, 
]{f(\x,\y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

To my surprise, it made the exterior of the contour black rather than transparent.

Any tips on how I can render the exterior of the contour transparent? This has me stumped.

how is this related to lua?

transparent is the same as black.
transparent!100, black and goes all the way trough gray to transparent!0, white. This makes more semantic sense in a tikzfadingfrompicture - a fading based on a grayscale picture. I do not believe that a colormap can be transparent. You could actually use a tikzfadingfrompicture for this, but much simpler:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=ln((1+\x)^2+\y^2)+ln((1+(7*\x)/2)^2+(49*\y^2)/4)+ln((1+4*\x)^2+16*\y^2);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
enlargelimits,
axis background/.style={pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=black!30},
]
\addplot3[
draw=none, forget plot,
contour external/file={temp_contour},
contour gnuplot={levels={1}, labels=false},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
]{f(\x,\y)};
\addplot3[blue, thick, fill=blue!50] table {temp_contour.table} -- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: With  contour filled in a tikzfadingfrompicture (no gnuplot). This solution is more complicated - will not recommend:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading,
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=ln((1+\x)^2+\y^2)+ln((1+(7*\x)/2)^2+(49*\y^2)/4)+ln((1+4*\x)^2+16*\y^2);
},
]
\begin{axis}[
name=shape,
view={0}{90},
xmin=-1.3, xmax=0.2,
ymin=-0.45, ymax=0.45,
axis lines=none,
colormap={CM}{color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!100)},
]
\addplot3[
contour filled={levels={1}},
domain=-1.2:0.1, samples=20,
domain y=-0.4:0.4, samples y=20,
]{f(\x,\y)};
\end{axis}
\path (0,0) circle[radius=10]; %encompassing circle for alignment
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
xmin=-1.3, xmax=0.2,
ymin=-0.45, ymax=0.45,
axis background/.style={pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=black!30},
]
\fill[path fading=myfading, fit fading=false, fill=blue!50] (shape.south west) rectangle (shape.north east); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


